# Pod fails to lounch on Kubernetes saying Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, deployment

I have dockarised two applications. having Tomcat on one image & Mysql on the other. I have tested it from browser and they are connected to eachother and working fine localy. Finally i pushed them on docker hub.

Afterwards I created ec2 Instance on aws where i have installed & configured kubernetes kops.
Then i created kluster on aws which is running just fine.

Now I'd like to deploy my dockerised images on the kluster which i just created on aws.

Deployment file below. When I run kubectl create -f dbdep.yml, it gets created but the pod fails to launch. I have provided usefull logs and errors below as well. So is this issue familiar for anyone???

```
db_backup.sql: 

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `role`;
CREATE TABLE `role` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



Dockerfile:
FROM mysql:8.0.33
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="pass"
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE="test"
ADD db_backup.sql docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_backup.sql

dbdep.yml:
 apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: db01
      labels:
        app: db01 
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: db01
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: db01
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: db01
              image: dash/db01:latest
              args:
                - '--ignore-db-dir'
                - 'lost+found'
              volumeMounts: 
                - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
                  name: db01-data
              ports:
                - name: vprodb-port
                  containerPort: 3306
              env:
                - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: app-secret 
                      key: db01-pass
          nodeSelector:
            zone: us-east-1a
          volumes: 
            - name: db01-data
              awsElasticBlockStore:
                volumeID: vol-0218587545484
                fsType: ext4 



 logs: 
 [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
 [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 
 [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
 Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened
 Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
 The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
 unknown option '--ignore-db-dir'.
 /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

I have recreated kluster twice but the error stays the same!

Comment: Your dockerised mysql image seems to have a different version to the one that is used when you run the pods.

Comment: It looks like whatever's in that EBS volume doesn't have the right file structure for that version of MySQL.  IME it's a little unusual to directly refer to EBS volumes like this; can you describe this as a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), have that create a PersistentVolumeClaim, and have the cluster allocate the EBS volume (or other storage)?

Comment: Hi thnaks for the answer.  1. I have built and pushed this image and it is the same image used for deployment..  2. the volume is successfully created and attached.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the volume created successfully. you can find in your AWS account in ebs section and find your volume via the volume id.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. yes volume gets created and successfully attached.